# Как суммировать любой элемент со списка на другой любой элемент с другого списка в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Если есть такие два списка:

```
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
digits = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

Я хочу суммировать один любой элемент с первого списка на один любой со второго. Поняла что `print(any(digits) + any(letters))` не работает, даже если я перевожу все элементы `digits` на `str`Желаемый результат: `A5`

Что посоветуете?

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1], zip(letters, digits)))`?

Comment: что значит "суммировать на"? и что значит "один любой"? покажите желаемый результат вашего примера.

Comment: `any()` возаращает `True` или `False`

Comment: `print(random.choice(digits) + random.choice(letters))` может вы имели ввиду это?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin да именно это. Спасибо!